# “pgAdmin 4” is damaged and can’t be opened

Tags: macos, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm running on Mac OSX EL Capitan 10.11.2.

I wan to install PgAdmin 4 to the computer, but when I open the app after the install I get this messages `“pgAdmin 4” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash.`

I'm using the download from here `https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v2.1/macos/`

Can anyone explain to me why I'm getting this meassges?
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `I open the app` you mean the installer or after install ?

Comment: I mean after the install :)

Comment: Have you set "Allow apps downloaded from" to "Anywhere"?

Comment: did you check if download installer size same as the original? did you try delete and install again?

Comment: I had to change  "Allow apps downloaded from" to "Anywhere".... I can open it now :)

Comment: You also can use the command from terminal that i posted below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under `System Preferences`, choose `Security & Privacy`. To fix the “Move to Trash” error, we need to change the **Allow apps downloaded from**: option to **Anywhere**.

or from CLI:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```